# Expected minimum of a finite random walk.

Tags: statistics, random-walk, expectation

So I couldn't find any resource for how to calculate the expected minimum of a random walk. Since it is such the minimum of the random variables are actually not independent as they are cumulative sums of random variables. Formally:

We are given some finite parameters $M,N \in \mathbb{N}$

Let $X_i \sim U(-M,M)$ for $i \in \{1,2,\dots,N\}$. In both cases of a continuous or discrete uniform I would be quite happy to find a solution, so you can assume whatever you prefer.

Let $Y_i=\sum_{j=1}^i X_j$ for $i \in \{1,2,\dots,N\}$

$E[\min(Y_i)]=?$

The only solution so far I found is simulation, but I was wondering for any approach for a analytical solution.

Comment: for a mean 0 random walk the minimum is not finite, and in general it is hard, and probably unsatisfactory,  but you could find a discussion in Spitzer's random walk book, or, I think, Feller Vol 2.

Comment: Mmm I probably forgot to add that it is a finite random walk, so we know it is suppose to take N steps. I'll modify the question.

Comment: I think you may want to look into Copula's. I think an analytical solution may be a bit a difficult because you will be taking the CDF of a joint distribution of a large number of rvs.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if $E[\min_i Y_i]$ was close to $\sqrt{\dfrac{2 N \sigma^2}{\pi}}$ for large $N$ where $\sigma^2$ is the variance of $X_i$ (e.g. $\sigma^2=M^2/3$ if $X_i$ is uniform in $[-M,M]$).

Comment: Could you share how you got the answer pls